# Nav menu clickable area extends way past the nav button

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

For some reason the social media icons on top of the left sidebar on www.hungryrunnergirl.com prevent the directly below archive widget from being clicked. I don't have this problem when I make each button position absolute (with the container remaining relative) but when I do that, The buttons appear in different places depending on which browser you are viewing from. Does anyone have any insight into why this could be happening (either the inconsistent positioning when using absolute or the un-clickable areas when using relative CSS positioning)?

Here's the code that I'm currently using to style the menu:

```
/* Menu Container */
.custom .sidebar .menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
  position: relative;
}
/* Facebook */
.custom #menu-item-15470 a {
    display:block;
height:81px;
width:80px;
padding:0px;
margin-left:0px;
position: relative;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
outline:none;
text-indent:-9999px;
background-image:url("http://www.hungryrunnergirl.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Social_Sprite.png"); background-position:-83px 0px;
}
.custom #menu-item-15470 a:hover { 
    background-position:0px 0; 
}
/* Pinterest */
.custom #menu-item-15471 a {
display:block;
height:81px;
width:80px;
padding:0px;
margin-left:10px;
position: relative;
left: 81px;
top: -81px;
outline:none;
text-indent:-9999px;
background-image:url("http://www.hungryrunnergirl.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Social_Sprite.png"); background-position:-83px -82px;
}
.custom #menu-item-15471 a:hover { 
    background-position:0px -82px; 
}
/* Instagram */
.custom #menu-item-15472 a {
display:block;
height:81px;
width:80px;
padding:0px;
margin-top:10px;
position: relative;
left: 0px;
top: -81px;
outline:none;
text-indent:-9999px;
background-image:url("http://www.hungryrunnergirl.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Social_Sprite.png"); background-position:-83px -165px;
}
.custom #menu-item-15472 a:hover { 
background-position:0px -165px; 
}
/* Twitter */
.custom #menu-item-15475 a {
display:block;
height:81px;
width:80px;
padding:0px;
margin-left:10px;
margin-top:10px;
position: relative;
left: 81px;
top: -172px;
outline:none;
text-indent:-9999px;
background-image:url("http://www.hungryrunnergirl.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Social_Sprite.png"); background-position:-83px -248px;
}
.custom #menu-item-15475 a:hover { 
background-position:0px -248px; 
}
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to `li.widget` (line 191):

```
position: relative;
z-index: 100;
```

Comment: Wow. That worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help. As a side-note, why does that work?

Comment: I spoke a little too soon. As soon as I added a submenu, it's being displayed in different locations depending on the browser. You can check it out if you hover over the Instagram icon on the bottom left. Also, if you hover below the icon just above the "marathon" text, the submenu is incorrectly activated. Any further suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: You've changed the layout by adding more widgets. Your original question was related to the Archive list, which had been solved above. Is it the pink Jane showing underneath the "Miles run" text that is the issue now?

Comment: The social menu is a custom nav menu that I placed using a Thesis hook. The z-value is only pushing that over-expanded clickable area below the social icons beneath the other widgets and therefore making "archive" clickable again. However, the problem now is three-fold. 1) The submenu displays in different places depending on the browser. i.e. Firefox: http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8376/8364431123_8787b479c9_b.jpg Safari: http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8326/8364431795_08f4c01c1e_b.jpg. 2) If you hover above the word "marathon" the submenu activates. 3) It's displayed behind the text.